If the speed $c$ in our universe were twice the value defined in $E=mc^2$, would the mass $m$ of the objects in this hypothesis be 1/4 of what it is?
I ask this question because in the expression $E=mc^2$, I realize that for a given object whose rest energy is $E$, the mass or inertia of this same object depends only on the value of $c$, which in our universe has a value of 300,000 km/s, but which could supposedly be 600,000 km/s (for example). In this hypothesis, the mass m that we know would only have a 1/4 of the value it has, and furthermore, if the speed $c$ were infinite, the objects would be devoid of inertia.
I think that although the speed $c$ is a constant in our universe, the inertia of objects depends only on its value, and that is why I believe that Mach's Principle, which attributes the value of $m$, or the inertia of objects, to the presence  of the mass of distant stars, is false.

I think the E would grow at the same rate. Instead of twice as large, think of the speed of light of 99.9% or 100.1% of what it is now. In those cases you would just adjust the energy output accordingly. So why would 200% be any different?

This question is incomplete and cannot be answered as it is. The speed of light is related to the fine structure constant, the elementary charge, Planck’s constant, and the vacuum permittivity. To tell how things would change you need to specify how each of any four of those quantities change. E.g. c doubles and e, h, and $\alpha$ stay constant.

Why do you think $E$ remains constant?

@foolishmuse - Yes, this is my reasoning, and you seem to agree with it, because you are hypothetically admitting that a certain mass m (assuming c = 100.1%) has a greater rest energy E than we are used to.

@vale 11 - Presenting a SUPPOSEDLY insurmountable obstacle is a disinterested way of trying to find a solution to the issue presented.
